# How to find and update the contents of a table?

Tags: php, html, smarty

I am currently helping out a friend with his website, I am doing so through a SVN, I have been updating information for him, however I have encountered a list of dates where I cannot find the source information for so I cannot update it.

Below is the code which I believe is pointing to the code I want to update `$item.ClassHours` how do I find where the source information is?

```
<table class="stripe-table" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Class Choice</th>
            <th class="clear-bg">Schedule</th>
            <th>Class Hours</th>
            <th class="clear-bg">Level</th>
        </tr>
        <volist name="article.content_complex.part_time" id="item">
            <notempty name="item.Schedule">
                <tr>
                    <notempty name="item.ClassChoice">
                        <th <notempty name="item.ClassChoice_rowspan">rowspan="{$item.ClassChoice_rowspan}"</notempty> >{$item.ClassChoice}</th>
                    </notempty>
                    <td>{$item.Schedule}</td>
                    <notempty name="item.ClassHours">
                        <th <notempty name="item.ClassHours_rowspan">rowspan="{$item.ClassHours_rowspan}"</notempty> >{$item.ClassHours}</th>
                    </notempty>
                    <notempty name="item.Level">
                        <td <notempty name="item.Level_rowspan">rowspan="{$item.Level_rowspan}"</notempty> >{$item.Level}</td>
                    </notempty>
                </tr>
            </notempty>
        </volist>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What you are asking for is very specific to your site. You would have to search all your pages for it. One such way is to open all your files in a text editor (preferably Notepad++) and click CTRL+F, and search for the term in all the documents. If you have them all open, it should pop-up.

Comment: Using netbeans allows to search your entire project. It's also a nice IDE

Comment: Do you know what type of file it would be saved as?